# How can I find out the temperature components are running at in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, overheating, temperature, diagnostic

The title of the question says it all really. I have a new laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. There appears to be an overheating problem which fortunately does not appear to be affecting performance. I suspect it is my nvidia geforce card, even though I have Bumblebee installed.

In essence what I am looking for is a way, either via terminal or an app, to monitor the temperature of components so as to definably find out what may be overheating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up for `lm-sensors` and `psensor`. Those will give you a command line output as well as a GUI for your laptop.

Here is a good tutorial how to use lm-sensors: [lm-sensors Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto)

Comment: unfortunately the Nvidia does not show up on this.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Nvidia card temperature, you can use `nvidia-settings` (if you're running the proprietary drivers):

```
$ nvidia-settings –q gpucoretemp

  Attribute 'GPUCoreTemp' (sylvain-Studio-XPS-1340:0.0): 51.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is an integer attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is a read-only attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' can use the following target types: X Screen, GPU.
```

51°C is was you're looking for.

Comment: this command returns the message ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target specification), specified in query 'gpucoretemp'.

Comment: @gman OK, please then try `optirun nvidia-smi`, you should get amongst other info the gpu temp

Comment: Had to enter optirun /locationfolder/nvidia-smi but it did give me an output. Looks like its at 39ºC. Thanks

Comment: @gman Good to know. Your heat problem is then somewhere else, better luck with sensor packages?